# run a (vectorized) function on only certain elements of the matrix

Tags: r, performance

I am looking to run `apply` or any variant of `apply` to a very large matrix (`317 x 317`). But I don't need to run this function on every single element, only those that meet a certain criteria. I also need to do this relatively fast and efficiently as I'm running quite a lot of simulations.

Consider the following `6 x 6` example:

```
> age
       [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]   [,6]
[1,]    102  20354 194756  75017  68475 193083
[2,]   2274  55366  99150 484081 313875 663767
[3,] 550372 335185 630170  34097 140279 453137
[4,] 275252 219612 332521 109914 263070 235245
[5,] 134672 321061 209240 315383 221653 493812
[6,] 441144 356907 450028 539093 683890 149454

> agedeath
       [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]   [,6]
[1,] 867240 683280 770880 630720 823440 604440
[2,] 543120 166440 674520 876000 876000 604440
[3,] 867240 411720 692040 762120 876000 858480
[4,] 823440 823440 867240 876000 876000 814680
[5,] 849720 849720 586920 508080 481800 876000
[6,] 814680 534360 508080 876000 586920 876000
```

The elements that are important to me are such that `age > agedeath`, ie the code

```
> which(age > agedeath, arr.ind = T)
     row col
[1,]   6   5
[2,]   2   6
```

My current method is

```
  ## check if they will die
  whodies <- which(age > agedeath, arr.ind = T)
  if(nrow(whodies) > 0){
    for(i in 1:nrow(whodies)){
      #whodies[i, 1] is the row, #whodies[i, 2] is the column
      switch_person(stateval, whodies[i, 1], whodies[i, 2])
    }
  }
```

I am hoping to find a different, possibly vectorized solution to this

The function that needs to be run on the elements `switch_person` takes in 3 arguments.

```
switch_person <- function(switchvalue, i, j){

  ## here we only set a swap. 
  ## the update function will take into account everything else like immunity

  #only run if swap hasnt been set before
  if(swap[i, j]==0){
    deref(swapref)[i,j] = switchvalue
    return(1) #return success
  }
  return(0) #return fail

}
```

`swap` is another matrix. So you can think I have a `age`, `agedeath`, `swap` matrix. If `age > agedeath` (for the `i,j` coordinate), I want to set their `swap[i, j] = some_value`

I am using the `ref` package so that I don't make a lot of copies of my matrices and can modify the original matrix.

Comment: This question seems to be about vectorising the function `switch_person`, in which case we probably need to see that function.

Comment: @jbaums I've added some more information

Comment: What are you trying to "vectorize"? The "i" and "j" arguments of `switch_person`? If, instead of `swap[i, j] = switchvalue`, you use `ij = cbind(i, j); swap[ij[!swap[ij], ]] = switchvalue` it seems that, this way, you could pass "i" and "j" of `length > 1`. If you're free to not use `switch_person` as is, it looks like you -just- need `swap[(age > agedeath) & (!swap)] = switchvalue`